# Modern approach of creating VHF FSK (FM) recieeiver

Tags: rf, receiver, frequency-modulation

I need to make a narrow band FM receiver for the VHF band. More specifically, not even FM, but FSK. The operating frequency range should include from 35 to 40 MHz. Frequency deviation is around 0.5 to 5 kHz. I have not found the exact data, but for example [this site](https://www.norcim-rc.club/Radio3.htm) assumes 0.75 kHz.
What are the options for building such a receiver on a relatively modern element base? The receiver itself should be compact, something like an Arduino module.

1. SDR. Yes, it works, but it's a cannon against a crow. In addition to the SDR reciever itself you need a computer like RPi, which is not cheap and not compact at all.
2. ICs like MC3359, MC3362. Despite the fact that they are not made anymore, it is easy to buy them. I even found a complete design of what I need
   https://www.instructables.com/Modularized-Narrowband-FM-Receiver/
   But these chips need an IF transformer (quad coil) which you can't buy anymore, at lest not in my area.
3. Ready-made PPM receivers of course exist, but they are rare and found mostly on eBay and without the possibility of delivery to me.

What is the adequate way to solve this problem? The only thing I came up with is a frequency upconversion with a mixer and a programmable oscillator (like si5351) to 70-110 MHz range and demodulation with something like tea5767 or rda5807m. But I think there should be a simpler approach.